# What does this "inverse" peak mean? (step function)

Tags: pid

I identified my system and now I am trying to tune PI regulator since I think I do not need D.

I came across this graph while Matlabing and I do not know what does it mean.

I am using pidtune() to get my P and I values. (I think computation is all correct, I made model in simulink to confirm). Anyway see my picture and arrow is pointing at what I do not understand. Why is my system going below zero first?

It is supposed to be water flow regulator.

[image]

Transfer function:
$$ \frac{-0.311s + 0.05548}{s^2 + 0.06882s + 0.0007626}$$

Continuous-time PI controller in parallel form:
$$K_p + K_i * \frac{1}{s}$$

With $K_p = 0.256$, $K_i = 0.000342$

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your system is starting at the zero state? (including 1st state derivatives and controller integrator)

Comment: Yes there is no point in starting something like water flow controller/system in minus values.

Comment: Is it coming from the `-0.311 s` in your transfer function?

Comment: I think its because I identified 1st order system as 2nd order system (arx command in Matlab).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to be concerned about is the well known nonminimum-phase effect of the zero $s_0=0.05548/0.311$ in the right half of the s-plane.

You should first ask yourself whether this lag has a physical interpretation in the context of your system. Many physical systems expose such a dynamics, but here it might also depend on how you carried out the identification.

Then, to properly account for such a lag, if it really exists and is not introduced by the identification process, you should make use of proper techniques. For example, look [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdigitool.library.colostate.edu%2Fwebclient%2FDeliveryManager%3Fpid%3D88646&ei=OzwDVPjXI4aN7Abl2IDQCA&usg=AFQjCNHDwLUAFgKeq1qyaPIbjuMP9o35eQ&sig2=F-5vNha3Bgg9Emlu8MryPg&bvm=bv.74115972,d.ZGU).